# Disabling the Adaptive Activation area in menus in Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4

Tags: kubuntu, menu

I use Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4 and it seems to use some sort of [Adaptive Activation area menu](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=15241043208475477030&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22), i.e. it  eliminates corner steering by default. This affects all applications I have tried (kickoff start menu, Eclipse, Google Chrome) so it seems to be a system setting.

[image]

(Source: E. Tanvir, J. Cullen, P. Irani and A. Cockburn. "[AAMU: Adaptive Activation Area Menus for Improving Selection in Cascading Pull-Down Menus](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=15241043208475477030&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)." CHI 2008.)

Is there anyway to disable Adaptive activation areas in the menu to allow corner steering?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.